# Estimating the parameter of a uniform distribution: improper prior?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, uniform-distribution, uninformative-prior

> We have N samples, $X_i$, from a uniform distribution $[0,\theta]$ where $\theta$ is unknown.  Estimate $\theta$ from the data.

So, Bayes' rule...

$f(\theta | {X_i}) = \frac{f({X_i}|\theta)f(\theta)}{f({X_i})}$

and the likelihood is:

$f({X_i}|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\theta}$
(edit: when $0 \le X_i \le \theta$ for all $i$, and 0 otherwise -- thanks whuber)

but with no other information about $\theta$, it seems like the prior should be proportional to $1$ (i.e. uniform) or to $\frac{1}{L}$ (Jeffreys prior?) on $[0,\infty]$ but then my integrals don't converge, and I'm not sure how to proceed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your likelihood is incorrect: it will be zero whenever $\theta$ is less than the largest $X_i$.

Comment: Can you show what integrals you are taking?

Comment: Yea, so, I guess I just don't know how to deal with the improper prior. E.g., I want to write
$f[X_i] = \int_\Theta f(X_i|\theta)f(\theta)d\theta$

Comment: For the improper prior, $f[X_i] = \int_\Theta f(X_i|\theta)f(\theta)d\theta$ = $\int_{\max(X_i)}^\infty \theta^{-N}d\theta$ = $\max(X_i)^{1-N}/(N-1)$ and for the prior $f(\theta)\propto 1/\theta$ you similarly obtain $\max(X_i)^{-N}/N.$ Because $\max{X_i}\gt 0$ almost surely, it is certain the integrals will converge.

Comment: The Bernardo reference posterior is Pareto - see the [catalog of noninformative priors](http://www.stats.org.uk/priors/noninformative/YangBerger1998.pdf).

Comment: This is not a Fisher model. Is there really a Jeffreys prior in such a case ?

Comment: $f[X_i] = \int_\Theta f(X_i|\theta)f(\theta)d\theta$ is the formula for the prior predictive distribution, it makes no sense if you consider a noninformative prior.

Comment: @Will, are you _constrained_ to apply Bayes' rule? In such a simple setting, the MLE for $\theta$ is just $\max(x_i)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has generated some interesting debate, but note that it really doesn't make much difference to the question of interest.  Personally I think that because $\theta$ is a scale parameter, the transformation group argument is appropriate, leading to a prior of

$$\begin{array}& p(\theta|I)=\frac{\theta^{-1}}{\log\left(\frac{U}{L}\right)}\propto\theta^{-1}  & L<\theta<U\end{array}$$

This distribution has the same form under rescaling of the problem (the likelihood also remains "invariant" under rescaling).  The kernel of this prior, $f(y)=y^{-1}$ can be derived by solving the functional equation $af(ay)=f(y)$.  The values $L,U$ depend on the problem, and really only matter if the sample size is very small (like 1 or 2).  The posterior is a truncated pareto, given by:

$$\begin{array}\\ p(\theta|DI)=\frac{N\theta^{-N-1}}{ (L^{*})^{-N}-U^{-N}} & L^{*}<\theta<U &
\text{where} & L^{*}=max(L,X_{(N)})
\end{array}$$
Where $X_{(N)}$ is the Nth order statistic, or the maximum value of the sample.  We get the posterior mean of
$$E(\theta|DI)= \frac{ N((L^{*})^{1-N}-U^{1-N}) }{ (N-1)((L^{*})^{-N}-U^{-N}) }=\frac{N}{N-1}L^{*}\left(\frac{ 1-\left[\frac{L^{*}}{U}\right]^{N-1} }{ 1-\left[\frac{L^{*}}{U}\right]^{N} }\right)$$
If we set $U\to\infty$ and $L\to 0$ the we get the simpler exression $E(\theta|DI)=\frac{N}{N-1}X_{(N)}$.

But now suppose we use a more general prior, given by $p(\theta|cI)\propto\theta^{-c-1}$ (note that we keep the limits $L,U$ to ensure everything is proper - no singular maths then).  The posterior is then the same as above, but with $N$ replaced by $c+N$ - provided that $c+N\geq 0$.  Repeating the above calculations, we the simplified posterior mean of

$$E(\theta|DI)=\frac{N+c}{N+c-1}X_{(N)}$$

So the uniform prior ($c=-1$) will give an estimate of $\frac{N-1}{N-2}X_{(N)}$ provided that $N\geq 2$ (mean is infinite for $N=2$). This shows that the debate here is a bit like whether or not to use $N$ or $N-1$ as the divisor in the variance estimate.

One argument against the use of the improper uniform prior in this case is that the posterior is improper when $N=1$, as it is proportional to $\theta^{-1}$.  But this only matters if $N=1$ or is very small.

Answer (score 3):

Since the purpose here is presumably to obtain some valid and useful estimate of $\theta$, the prior distribution *should be consistent* with the specification of the distribution of the population from which the sample comes. This does NOT in any way mean that we "calculate" the prior using the sample itself -this would nullify the validity of the whole procedure. We do know that the population from which the sample comes is a population of  i.i.d. uniform random variables each ranging in $[0,\theta]$. This is a *maintained assumption* and is part of the prior information that we possess (and it has nothing to do with the *sample*, i.e. with a specific realization of a subset of these random variables).

Now assume that this population consists of $m$ random variables, (while our sample consists of $n<m$ realizations of $n$ random variables). The maintained assumption tells us that
$$\max_{i=1,...,n}\{X_i\}\le \max_{j=1,...,m}\{X_j\} \le \theta$$

Denote for compactness $\max_{i=1,...,n}\{X_i\} \equiv X^*$. Then we have $\theta \ge X^*$ which can also be written 
$$\theta = cX^*\qquad c\ge 1$$

The density function of the $\max$ of $N$ i.i.d Uniform r.v.'s ranging in $[0,\theta]$ is 
$$f_{X^*}(x^*) = N\frac {(x^*)^{N-1}}{\theta^N}  $$

for the support $[0,\theta]$, and zero elsewhere. Then by using $\theta = cX^*$ and applying the change-of-variable formula we obtain a prior distribution for $\theta$ that is consistent with the maintained assumption:
$$f_p(\theta) = N\frac {(\frac{\theta}{c})^{N-1}}{\theta^N}\frac 1c = \frac {N}{c^N} \theta^{-1}\qquad \theta \in [x^*, \infty]$$

which may be improper if we don't specify the constant $c$ suitably. But our interest lies in having a proper *posterior* for $\theta$, and also, we do not want to  restrict the possible values of $\theta$ (beyond the restriction implied by the maintained assumption). So we leave $c$ undetermined.
Then writing $\mathbf X = \{x_1,..,x_n\}$ the posterior is

$$f(\theta \mid \mathbf X)\; \propto\; \theta^{-N}\frac {N}{c^N} \theta^{-1} \Rightarrow  f(\theta \mid \mathbf X) = A\frac {N}{c^N} \theta^{-(N+1)}$$

for some normalizing constant A. We want 
$$\int_{S_{\theta}}f(\theta \mid \mathbf X)d\theta =1 \Rightarrow \int_{x^*}^{\infty}A\frac {N}{c^N} \theta^{-(N+1)}d\theta =1$$

$$\Rightarrow A\frac {N}{c^N}\frac {1}{-N}\theta^{-N}\Big |_{x^*}^{\infty} = 1 \Rightarrow A = (cx^*)^N$$

Inserting into the posterior
$$f(\theta \mid \mathbf X) = (cx^*)^N\frac {N}{c^N} \theta^{-(N+1)} = N(x^*)^N\theta^{-(N+1)} $$

Note that the undetermined constant $c$ of the prior distribution has conveniently cancelled out.

The posterior summarizes all the information that the specific sample can give us regarding the value of $\theta$. If we want to obtain a specific value for $\theta$ we can easily calculate the expected value of the posterior,
$$E(\theta\mid \mathbf X) = \int_{x^*}^{\infty}\theta N(x^*)^N\theta^{-(N+1)}d\theta = -\frac{N}{N-1}(x^*)^N\theta^{-N+1}\Big |_{x^*}^{\infty} = \frac{N}{N-1}x^*$$

Is there any intuition in this result? Well, as the number of $X$'s increases, the more likely is that the maximum realization among them will be closer and closer to their upper bound, $\theta$ - which is exactly what the posterior mean value of $\theta$ reflects: if, say, $N=2 \Rightarrow E(\theta\mid \mathbf X) = 2x^*$, but if $N=10 \Rightarrow E(\theta\mid \mathbf X) = \frac{10}{9}x^*$.
This shows that our tactic regarding the selection of the prior was *reasonable* and *consistent* with the problem at hand, but not necessarily "optimal" in some sense.

Comment: Basing the prior on the data sounds fishy to me.  How do you justify this approach?

Comment: I didn't base the prior on the _data_. I based the prior on the knowledge that the sample comes from a population of non-negative uniform random variables that have as an upper bound the unknown parameter.

Comment: @Whuber forgot to alert you for my previous comment. I continue: we cannot perform Bayesian estimation knowing only that a sample exists. In order to form the likelihood, we must know (or assume) the distribution of the sample. And I used only just this information, nothing more. Notice that the unknown constant $c$ in the prior is not given a numerical value, and it does not appear in the posterior distribution.

Comment: I agree with this, but I think the way you phrased it in the answer is confusing. All you are really saying is that the model is one of iid data from a Uniform$(0,\theta)$ distribution; your remarks appear directed at the fact that its pdf is *not* $f(x)=1/\theta$ (which is not a valid pdf at all) but actually is $f(x)=(1/\theta)\times I(0\le x\le \theta)$.

Comment: @whuber. Indeed. Although all pdf's should be defined for all R, being zero at places, especially for the uniform distribution the proper definition is critical because otherwise one "loses sight" of the $x$'s. Can you please indicate the part of my answer that misleads the reader into thinking that I am "calculating" the prior from the sample? I would like to change it, so no such confusion remains. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Sorry; I should have said. The phrases "we know that $\theta$ must be higher than their maximum, if the likelihood is to be non-zero" and "So the condition $\max_i\{X_i\} \le \theta$ (referring to the random variable, not the realized sample values of the $X$'s), should be used in determining a suitable prior," made me concerned you might be suggesting that some analysis of the data (based on the maximum) should be used to determine the prior, even though you do distinguish the RV from the observations. That condition restricts the *likelihood,* not the prior.

Comment: @whuber Changes made. I believe now there is no confusion regrading the issue of the prior.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Your argument $\theta=cX^*$ has a fiducial flavor. Or is something else ? I cannot figure out how to give a rigorous sense to your approach ($c=\frac{\theta}{X^*}$ is a "constant", what does it mean ?)

Comment: @Stephane Laurent $\theta = cX^*\; c\ge 1$ is a construction _consistent with the population distributional assumption_. Why, for it to be _valid_ (again, not "optimal") does it need more rigor than that?

Comment: I am mathematician and I don't understand the nature of this equality. Is $c$ random or not ? Where is randomness in this equality ? Where do you use the fact that $c\geq 1$ ? I claimed this looks like the fiducial argument because it seems to rely  on a confusion with randomness as in the fiducial argument for a Gaussian observation : $x = \mu + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim {\cal N}(0,1)$ then $\mu = x-\epsilon$ and then we take $\mu \sim {\cal N}(x, 1)$ as the fiducial distribution. I'm just trying to understand how is it funded. Sorry for mistakes in my English, it's late. (cc @whuber)

Comment: @Stephane Laurent Given the distributional assumption on the population (i.i.d. uniform ranging in $[0,\theta]$), we have that $\theta \ge X^*$. The expression $\theta = cX^*,\; c\ge 1$ is an expression _consistent_ with $\theta \ge X^*$. So we can start with the former as our prior. That's all there is to it. I nowhere implied that it is the "best" or the "true" prior. $c$ is a constant, not random. $c\ge 1$ reflects that the lower bound of of $\theta$ is $\max {X}$.

Comment: I have nothing against the fact that your prior is not "the best". Where did I say something like that ? I'm just trying to understand your approach. I don't understand this equality yet. If $c$ is constant in the equality $\theta=cX^*$, does that mean that both $X^*$ and $\theta$ are nonrandom ? By the way you don't **use** the fact that $c \geq 1$ in the derivation of the prior, do you ? (cc @whuber)

Comment: @Stephane Laurent. Let $Z$ be a r.v. then we can define another r.v. $Y = aZ$ where $a$ is a constant. This does not make $Z$ and $Y$ non-random, where did you get such an idea? Indeed,  $c\ge 1$ it is not used (as a numerical inequality) in the derivation of the prior

Comment: I didn't get such an idea, I'm only asking. Thus you mean that the correlation between $\theta$ and $X^*$ is $1$ ? It's strange too. It's strange too that $c \geq 1$ is not used whereas you claim the equality with $c \geq 1$ is the "maintained assumption". And if $\theta = c X^*$ is an almost sure equality with both $\theta$ and $X^*$ random, that would mean that the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is the Dirac mass at $cx^*$ ? Many strange interrogations.

Comment: And the support of your prior depends on the data ? ($\theta \in [x^*, \infty[$)

Comment: @Stephane : indeed, a consequence of this prior assumption is that the correlation is 1. I don't see any problem in not using, in the way you mean, the inequality related to $c$ -I am using a _consequence_ of this inequality. The posterior distribution is derived in my answer by the standard method, I honestly don't know what else to comment on that.

Comment: @Stephane The lower bound of the support depends on the maximum value of the sample, otherwise, given the distributional assumption for the population, the prior would be incompatible and would lead to useless inference. Still I do not specify this bound as a specific numerical value - it just says that "no matter what the maximum value of the sample is, the support of $\theta$ cannot include lower values than it"

Comment: A prior depending (even if this is only through the support) on the data sounds wrong: **you cannot know the maximum of the sample before the sample has been generated**. Moreover, you claim that $\theta = cX^*$ is an almost sure equality, with both $\theta$ and $X^*$ random (thus there is correlation $1$). But this implies that the posterior distribution of $\theta$ (which is the conditional distribution of $\theta$ given the sample) is the Dirac mass at $cx^*$. And this contradicts your derivation of the posterior distribution. ... (no characters left...)

Comment: Your posterior distribution is rather the posterior distribution we obtain if we start by assuming that the $\theta$ has **the same distribution** as $c X^*$, up to truncation, or something like that (cc @whuber)

Comment: @Stephane I agree, I do not know the maximum of the sample when specifying the prior -this does not forbid me of using it as a symbol without specifying a numerical value for it, I just need to know that it will exist. To me the most critical comment is what you say about the issue with the Dirac mass. This would mean that the consequent application of Bayes theorem in this particular case becomes in some way wrong, or "forbidden" -... I would be really grateful if you could show this in order for me to understand it. Perhaps in an answer?

Comment: The  posterior distribution of $\theta$ is Dirac at $cx^*$ means that $\theta$ **is** $cx^*$. Bayes theorem is not the cause. You destroy everything by assuming $\theta = cX^*$. This implies $X^*=\theta/c$, thus the conditional distribution of $X^*$ given $\theta$ is the Dirac mass at $\theta/c$, whereas the original assumption is that this distribution is the uniform distribution on $(0,\theta)$.

Comment: @ Stephane, But Stephane, the assumption for uniform distribution on $(0,\theta)$ is an assumption that applies to the $X$'s, not to the $X^*$ which is the maximum of the $X$'s. I am losing you here.

Comment: Alecos and @Stéphane, if either of you is given the option to move this discussion to a chat room, please do so--it's getting too long to be useful here.

Comment: @whuber I leave the discussion now. See both of you elsewhere.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos You're right, sorry. But $x^*$ given $\theta$ is not Dirac in the original model. Sorry I leave this discussion now, it takes me too much time. See you.

Comment: @whuber I apologize, I was caught up in understanding what Stephane was trying to say.

Comment: Note that your generic approach via the use of $f_p(\theta)$ depends crucially on how you choose to introduce the variable $c$ into the problem.  For example, I could just as easily write $\theta=X^{*}+c$ for some $c>0$.  Then we obtain $g_p(\theta) = N\frac{(\theta-c)^{N-1}}{\theta^{N}}=N\left(1-\frac{c}{\theta}\right)^{N-1}\theta^{-1}$.  This is slightly different from the $f_p(\theta)$ that you use, and also depends on $c$.  So this approach is difficult to generalise "objectively" without some further rules to help decide how to introduce extra variables. (cc @StéphaneLaurent @whuber)

Comment: @probabilityislogic Indeed we could, as well as specifying many other alternatives, much more complicated functionally, that would be consistent with the prior information. But the issue with the choice of the prior is exactly, to _choose_ it, and my answer was in the spirit "let's see where we will be led if we use basic logical arguments and consistent choices for the case at hand", it was not meant as some "standard", "textbook" or "generally valid" approach.

Comment: If this is the case, then why not just choose a prior directly and "see where we will be led"?  Why bother with the extra work?

Comment: @probabilityislogic Who said that we shouldn't? I had an intellectually stimulating idea (obviously for my intellect and possibly for none other's), and I worked it out (i.e. the "extra work" was its own joy). I did not operate under any time- or cost- efficiency constraints (which, being an economist, I would have taken seriously into account if they were imposed). I did not then, nor do I now, consider my approach to be "best", or "better than..." - I haven't even tried to assess it from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

## Uniform Prior Distribution Theorem (interval case):

"If the totality of Your information about $\theta$ external to the data $D$ is captured by the single proposition
$$B=\{\{\text{Possible values for } \theta\}=\{\text{the interval } (a,b)\},a<b\}$$
then Your only possible logically-internally-consistent prior specification is
$$f(\theta)=\text{Uniform}(a,b)$$

Thus, you prior specification should correspond to the Jeffrey's prior if you truly believe in the above theorem."

Not part of the Uniform Prior Distribution Theorem:

Alternatively you could specify your prior distribution $f(\theta)$ as a Pareto distribution, which is the conjugate distribution for the uniform, knowing that you posterior distribution will have to be another uniform distribution by conjugacy.  However, if you use the Pareto distribution, then you will need to specify parameters of the Pareto distribution in some sort of way.

Comment: First you say the "only possible logically internally consistent" answer is a uniform distribution and then you proceed to propose an alternative.  That sounds illogical and inconsistent to me :-).

Comment: Oh those are not my words, I was merely quoting a the theorem.  However, I would disagree with you because "If the totality of Your information about θ external to the data D is captured by the single proposition", so if that was the ONLY thing you knew then the best you can do is to use that theorem.  I don't think you can make the Pareto uninformative so using it would require some other knowledge which you do not have if you use the first theorem :) Agreed?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect where the theorem starts and ends.

Comment: I can't agree. For instance, $B$ is also the set $\{\theta | \theta^3\in(a^3, b^3)\}.$ When $\Theta\sim\text{Uniform}(a,b),$ the PDF of $\Psi=\Theta^3$ is $1/(3\psi^{2/3}(b-a))$ for $a^3\lt \psi\lt b^3$. But according to the "theorem," $\Psi\sim\text{Uniform}(a^3,b^3)$ whose pdf is $1/(b^3-a^3)$ in that interval. In short, although the *proposition* does not depend on how the problem is parameterized, the "theorem"'s conclusion does depend on the parameterization, whence it is ambiguous.

Comment: BabakP: How could one say this is a *theorem* ? A theorem is a mathematical claim with a mathematical proof. This "theorem" would be more appropriately termed as a "principle", but it is not sensible because it is contradictory, as shown by @whuber.

Comment: Argue that with David Draper: http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ams221/Spring13/ams-221-lecture-notes-part-2-version-4.pdf slide 48

Comment: Thanks for the reference BabakP. I would like to point out that the "proof sketch" is bogus. Draper divides the interval into a finite number of equally spaced values and "passes to the limit." Anybody can divide the interval into values spaced to approximate any density they like and similarly pass to the limit, producing *perfectly arbitrary* "only possible logically-internally-consistent prior specifications." This kind of stuff--namely, using bad mathematics in an effort to show that non-Bayesians are illogical--gives Bayesian analysis an (undeservedly) bad name. (cc @Stéphane.)

Comment: BabaP: I don't know what "bogus" means, as said by @whuber, but for me there's no real mathematics in these slides. And anyway the principle is contradictory.

Comment: @Stéphane Please forgive my insensitivity (*insensibilité*)--I admire your skill at interacting here in a second language and do not knowingly use obscure terms!  [Bogus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bogus) is an adjective that comes from a 200-year old US slang term referring to a machine for counterfeiting money. In this case it's a mathematical machine for counterfeiting theorems :-).

Comment: Did you read the slides you linked to?  It only applies to a bounded interval and his reasoning is correct in my opinion.  He then says: "Intuitive extension of the previous results suggests trying a Uniform$(0; \infty)$ (improper) prior…, which I assume he shows to be incorrect since he cites Jeffreys and Janes.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for enriching my culture. Anyway I do not judge the author of these slides. Slides are just a support for a talk, and we do not know the intention of the author.