# What is a good example of a non-informative prior for the uniform distribution?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, uniform-distribution, uninformative-prior, jeffreys-prior

I recently noticed that for non-informative priors, people usually use something like a uniform prior, which works for many different distributions. However, assuming that your likelihood is nothing more than a uniform $\frac{1}{\theta}$ for a parameter theta, what is a non-informative prior that works here? The first thing coming to mind is the Jeffrey's prior, but that yields $-\frac{1}{\theta^2}$, which when trying to calculate the posterior mean / variance leads to a divergent series when trying to sum across the product of the prior and likelihood. Does anyone have any ideas of what is a good non-informative prior?

Comment: To be clear, this prior is a Pareto(1, 1) distribution. The posterior form is known and has finite moments: Pareto(max(1, data), 1 + sample_size). The fact that the prior does not have a finite first moment shouldn't scare us as long as it is a distribution (e.g., using a Cauchy distribution as a prior). So I'm a little confused as to what the problem is exactly?

Comment: Are you talking about a Uniform$(0,\theta)$?. (Note that the prior is for the parameter, rather than a distribution.)

Comment: @Matt What I mean is that if I want a prior where the expectation and variance exist, what should I choose?

Comment: **Warning:** Your likelihood is more than $1/\theta$ in that there is an indicator at play: $\mathbb{I}_{0\le x\le \theta}$.

Comment: A similar question with answers:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69383/estimating-the-parameter-of-a-uniform-distribution-improper-prior

Answer (score 2):

I will assume your model is a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, \theta)$.   So let $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ iid with that distribution, with $\theta>0$. Then the likelihood function can be written
$$
   L(\theta) = \theta^{-n} \cdot \mathbb{1}(\theta \ge T)
$$
where $T=\max_{i=1}^n X_i$.  The first idea is the Jeffrey' prior, and your statement of that cannot be right (it is negative!). What I get is $n/\theta$ for $\theta \ge T$. That may look strange, first, it depends on the data through $T$. But in this case that isn't a problem, since the likelihood is zero for $\theta < T$, so the prior on that interval is unimportant, it will always be multiplied with zero when calculating the posterior. Second, it is improper, but, as long as $n\ge 2$ it leads to a proper posterior (which do have the pareto form).  A detailed [development is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79275/jeffreys-prior-for-continuous-uniform-distribution/372347#372347).

The posterior is 
$$
   f(\theta | T) = \frac{n-1}{\theta}\cdot\left(\frac{T}{\theta}\right)^{n-1}
$$ for $\theta \ge T$.

For more information see [this paper](https://tminka.github.io/papers/minka-uniform.pdf).  A more thorough paper [is this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10691898.1998.11910622).